# How to test pwr_led on front panel header

Tags: motherboard

My power LED isn't lighting up when I turn my motherboard on (custom build), even though I've verified the LED works fine with a multimeter.  I've tested and used 2 different cables as well because I thought the first one had a bad connection, but I've verified the second one works as well.

Motherboard is a [Zotac IONITX-A-U](http://www.zotacusa.com/zotac-ion-itx-a-series-ionitx-a-u.html)

How do I test the pwr_led pins on the motherboard to find my problem?

Comment: Both LEDs work when tested with the multimeter and when touched directly to the front panel pins on the mobo.

Comment: Did you try plugging the LED in the other direction? LED stands for Light Emitting Diode. Diodes only allow power to flow through them in one direction.